# Compute Area of Polygon with a slope/angle?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I can calculate area of polygon using google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea? But how to calculate area of polygon with some inclination/slope/angle? The problem is that I have angle/slope and polygon points, I need to compute area.

Comment: Are you having trouble with the math or the coding?

Comment: @Diodeus, I need formula or any available method or any API to calculate area with slope?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=area+of+polygon

Comment: Thanks, from some of the links don't about slope/angle/inclination. I know how to calculate area of polygon with 0 slope. But having problem with non zero slopes.

Comment: [area of polygon](http://www.mathopenref.com/coordpolygonarea2.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer,

**Area = Area / Cos(angle)**